# Solution to diff eq

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Check whether the function $y=\sin(3x)/3$ is a solution of $xy'+y+3\cos3x$ with the initial condition $y(\pi)=0$

Find $xy'$ for the function $y=\sin(3x)/3$

I am a ex-math minor who is just trying to get through this summer class. My professor told us nothing about these. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: You haven't written a differential equation. Did you want $\dots=0$? If so, just plug $y$ into the equation and see if it holds. There aren't any "differential equations" techniques here, it's just ordinary calculus/algebra.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $y=\frac{\sin(3x)}{3}$, then $y'=\cos(3x)$. So replacing in the expression $$xy'+y+3\cos(3x)=x\cos(3x)+\frac{\sin(3x)}{3}+3\cos(3x)$$ cannot be zero. So $y=\frac{\sin(3x)}{3}$ is not a solution of the differential equation.

For the second part of the problem, assuming that $$xy'+y+3\cos(3x)=0$$ you are asked for $xy'$. Isolate this term from the equation and replace $y$ by its given expression.

I am sure that you can take from here.